# How Express recorgonizes middlewares?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm novice in Express and a little bit confused about how it handles middlewares?  So basically I have two middlewares which looks like:

```
app.use(require('_/app/middlewares/errors/404'))
app.use(require('_/app/middlewares/errors/500'))
```

**404**

```
var log = require('_/log')

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    log.warn('page not found', req.url)
    res.status(404).render('errors/404')
}
```

**500**

```
var log = require('_/log')

module.exports = function (er, req, res, next) {
    log.error(er.message)

    res.locals.error = er
    res.status(500).render('errors/500')
}
```

So now I want to add my custom middleware `app.use(require('_/app/middleware/shareLocals'))` which looks like:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.base_url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');

    next();
}
```

The main problem is that now when I try to use `base_url` I get `404` error...

So how `Express` understands what middleware do? That is between my middleware and 404 are no visual differences:

- it receives same params
- it doesn’t have any `if's` in it, just throws 404 error

Appears the feeling the middlewares in `Express` are made for errors (when excepts err as first param) and for 404 (when there is no first err)...

**P.S.**
Is there any difference defining middlewares before or after routes?

Answer (score 1):

> P.S. Is there any difference defining middlewares before or after routes?
>   Yes.

The order in which you register your middlewares (and routes) have a lot to say.

Image express as a giant list. Starting at the first element in the list, you have the first middleware OR route you have defined, next is the second, etc.

When express gets a request, it appears to be matching your route/name of route/middleware, and if it's a hit, it executes the middleware/route and potentially waits for a "next()" call.

So if you have a route "/test" it will only be executed if you have a request matching "/test". routes with different names obviously wont get triggered. middlewares can also have names: app.use("/test", middlewareA). This will also only trigger if "/test" is requested. The way you do it, all requests (within the routes namespace) will be triggered app.use(middlewareA). It's like a wildcard.

Now, to the implications of things being ordered:
Your 404 middleware should only be used AFTER all routes have been defined. that way, when the list reached the 404 middleware, no routes have actually been found.

returning/sending result/not calling next() at the end of a middleware will all potentially create problems in your flow. I wont go into details about this, but be aware of it.

I am guessing your own middleware is added after the 404 middleware. That is probably the problem. If not, you should surrender more of your code so we can take a better look. But remember, order is everything :)